# save separated ndarray predictions as csv file

Tags: python

```
dans=pd.read_csv('ans.csv', header=0)
dataa=dans
for x in dataa['ideas']:
    token=tokenizer.texts_to_matrix([x], mode='tfidf')
    c=model.predict(np.array(token))
    #cc=model.predict_classes(token)
    cc=np.argmax(c,axis=1)
    xc=encoder.inverse_transform(cc)
    print((xc))
```

I want save the results of xc in a csv file. It just save last prediction in xc not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
dans=pd.read_csv('ans.csv', header=0)
results = dans['A_COLUMN_NAME']
results['Prediction'] = 0
idx = 0
dataa=dans
for x in dataa['ideas']:
    token=tokenizer.texts_to_matrix([x], mode='tfidf')
    c=model.predict(np.array(token))
    #cc=model.predict_classes(token)
    cc=np.argmax(c,axis=1)
    xc=encoder.inverse_transform(cc)
    results['Prediction'].iloc[idx] = xc
    idx += 1
    print((xc)) 
results.to_csv('Results.csv')
```

just been super lazy here -> `results = dans['A_COLUMN_NAME']`

You can try classier `results = pd.DataFrame(index=dans.index)` :)

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: I edited the answer, try copy pasting now.